# Can't get form to submit properly with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a form which will add a book to a db of library books, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.  Here's my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="page-header">Add Books</h2>
            <br>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $host="*****"; // Host name 
    $username="*****"; // Mysql username 
    $password="******"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="******"; // Database name 

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

    $name=$_POST['Name'];
    $author=$_POST['Author'];
    $published=$_POST['Published'];
    $isbn=$_POST['ISBN'];
    $category=$_POST['Category'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO Library (Name, Author, Published, ISBN, Category)
    VALUES('$name', '$author', '$published', '$isbn', '$category')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($query){
        echo "Successfully Added!";
    }else{
        echo "Error"."<br />".$sql.mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
?> 
<br>
<form name="addBookForm" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="frmName">Book Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="frmName" placeholder="Name" name="Name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="frmAuthor">Author</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="frmAuthor" placeholder="Author" name="Author">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="frmPublished">Published</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="frmPublished" placeholder="Published" name="Published">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="frmISBN">ISBN</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="frmISBN" placeholder="ISBN" name="ISBN">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="frmCategory">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="frmCategory" name="Category">
            <option value="Politics/Philosophy">Politics/Philosophy</option>
            <option value="History / Labour History">History / Labour History</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Add Book</button>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been banging my head against a wall all day, is anybody able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?  When I press the submit button, it just posts back to the page without any success or error message, the when I check the db, the data was not inserted.  It's like it just refreshes the page.

Comment: Tell us what is going wrong.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you have no element `submit` in your form, so your `$_POST['submit']` check will always come back false, skipping all of the DB code anyways.

Comment: Try it -> if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  ==  'POST){ <- instead of -> if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging?

Comment: Marc B, I thought the button was the submit element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

$_POST['submit']...alright, it's a form input, with the name of submit. A button, perhaps? =P

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Add Book</button>
```

GASP! There's no name!

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Add Book</button>
```

There we go.

Comment: No problem, friend =)

Comment: Dump super globals such as $_POST to help you debug next time.